# Can't remove or overwrite my useRef list in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

Hi I have a useRef list of my audio elements. Every time a user connects to webRTC, then the UserID is stored in the `connectionList`. This also creates another audio element and stores it in the `remoteAudioStreamList` useRef list. If the user disconnects, then the useRef list of audio elements should be reduced by one element. This does not seem to work. Although I overwrite the list I always get a message that the element is still there.

Here is the code, where the `remoteAudioStreamList` get audio elements

```
          {connectionList.map((stream, index) => (

            <React.Fragment key={stream.id}>
              <audio ref={el => {
                if (index >= remoteAudioStreamList.current.length) {
                  remoteAudioStreamList.current.push({
                    stream: el,
                    fromUserID: connectionList[index].fromUserID
                  });
                }
              }} autoPlay ></audio>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
```

And here is the code where I try to reduce my `remoteAudioStreamList`

```
      let tempAudioStreamList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < remoteAudioStreamList.current.length; i++) {
        console.log(remoteAudioStreamList.current[i].fromUserID != msgDispatcher.fromUserID);
        if (remoteAudioStreamList.current[i].fromUserID != msgDispatcher.fromUserID) {
          tempAudioStreamList.push(remoteAudioStreamList.current[i]);
          console.log("tempList ",tempAudioStreamList);
          console.log(remoteAudioStreamList.current[i]);
        }
      }
      console.log(tempAudioStreamList)
      console.log(tempAudioStreamList == []);
      remoteAudioStreamList.current = tempAudioStreamList;
      console.log(remoteAudioStreamList.current);
```

I have many console logs bcause I want to understand it. And here is my example.

**Example**
I have a total of 2 users. That means one is the remote user. If the remote user disconnects, then `remoteAudioStreamList` is searched for users that do not have the ID of `msgDispatcher`. But since there is only 1 user who disconnects, the `tempAudioStreamList` must be empty. The empty list should then overwrite the `remoteAudioStreamList`. But the list is not empty.

***Console logs***

```
App.jsx:44 msgDispatcher {fromUserID: '42664dea-2982', pcCommand: 'disconnected'}
App.jsx:210 disconnected
App.jsx:214 false
App.jsx:221 tempAudioStreamList:> []
App.jsx:222 false
App.jsx:224 AudioStreamList >[]
```

when i click on the empty lists i get the following:

````
tempAudioStreamList:  
[]
0
: 
{stream: null, fromUserID: '42664dea-2982'}
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
AudioStreamList 
[]
0
: 
{stream: null, fromUserID: '42664dea-2982'}
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```
I don't understand why an element that is empty has an element and useRef doesn't override it. Please help
````